# How can I run WSDLToJava from a build.gradle file?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I am successfully able to run the WSDLToJava class from the command line to generate JaxB classes from a WSDL.

```
   java -Xmx128M  
        -cp "C:\cxf\apache-cxf-3.1.6\lib\cxf-manifest.jar;
             C:\java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\tools.jar"
        -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\cxf\apache-cxf-3.1.6
         \etc\logging.properties" 
         org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava 
         -d generated -frontend jaxws21 -b C:\Project\jaxb-bindings.xml 
          C:\Project\Service.wsdl
```

How can I run the same command line from a "build.gradle" file?  I am completely new to Gradle.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Pete

Comment: probably best by not using a plain shell [`Exec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task, but by using a [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task, like they do in https://gist.github.com/nilsmagnus/4965930 or https://github.com/gmateo/apache-cxf-example/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Thank you zap1 for the suggestion will look into this.

Answer (score 3):

While there are some Gradle plugins that implement this, I think it's just as easy to make the call directly via a `JavaExec` task.  Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
ext.cxfVersion = "3.1.6"

configurations {
    wsdl2java
}

dependencies {
    wsdl2java("org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:${cxfVersion}")
    wsdl2java("org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:${cxfVersion}")
    wsdl2java("org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:${cxfVersion}")
}

task wsdl2java(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava"
    classpath = configurations.wsdl2java
    // Uncomment to add JVM arguments if necessary (e.g. for cert-based security)
    //jvmArgs = [
    //    "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${keystorePath}",
    //    "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${keystorePassword}"
    //]
    args = [
        "-d", "src/gen/java",
        "example.wsdl"
        // Uncomment and remove the previous line to run for multiple WSDL files
        //"-wsdlList, "wsdls.txt"
    ]
}

// If you want to be able to debug the wsdl2java task from Eclipse, add the following
//eclipse {
//    classpath {
//        plusConfiguration += [configurations.wsdl2java]
//    }
//}
```

Execute the task by running `gradlew wsdl2java`.

Comment: Thank you for 
1) he above suggestion
2) Editing my question to be more clear.

Comment: I get an error on the line "classpath = configurations.wsdl2java" :                   Type mismatch.
Required:
FileCollection
Found:
NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration>

Comment: I am trying with the -wsdlList option, what should be the content of wsdls.txt? How should be this structured?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've run this, but I would try a plaintext file with a single WSDL per line.